# NVARCHAR being treated as XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have written this query to concatenate all the columns together but its always throwing this error:
query:

```
DECLARE @SCHEMA VARCHAR(25) = 'PERSON'
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(25) = 'PERSON'
DECLARE @I INT =1
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #COLUMNS
SELECT
  ORDINAL_POSITION,
  COLUMN_NAME
INTO #COLUMNS
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLE_NAME

DECLARE @NUMBER_OF_COLUMN INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #COLUMNS)

DECLARE @COLUMNLIST NVARCHAR(MAX)
WHILE @I<@NUMBER_OF_COLUMN
BEGIN
    SET @COLUMNLIST = ISNULL(@COLUMNLIST,
        (SELECT COLUMN_NAME
         FROM #COLUMNS
         WHERE ORDINAL_POSITION = @I
        )) + ', ' +
        (SELECT COLUMN_NAME
         FROM #COLUMNS
         WHERE ORDINAL_POSITION = @I)
    SET @I = @I + 1
END

DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT CONCAT('+@COLUMNLIST+') FROM Person.Person'
EXEC (@QUERY)
```

Error:

> Implicit conversion from data type xml to nvarchar is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Error seems to be from this line of code:`DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT CONCAT('+@COLUMNLIST+') FROM Person.Person'`

How do I solve it?

Comment: You should **avoid** writing your whole question in **ALL CAPS** - this is generally considered **SHOUTING** at your audience, it's rude and offensive, and dramatically lowers your chances of folks taking their time to read your question and provide an answer. Don't do it - just don't .

Comment: If I were to guess... have you executed a previous query in the same SSMS tab where there was `#COLUMNS` table whose `COLUMN_NAME` column was of type `xml`? Try copy-pasting your query into a new SSMS tab and executing it there.

Comment: Hi, @AlwaysLearning thanks for the response I tried your method it did not work.
For some reason, SQL considers columnlist as XML when I use it in a query

Comment: @AdityaArya what you posted has nothing to do with XML. It's a slow method of aggregating strings. All SQL Server versions in mainstream support, ie 2017 and later, have `STRING_AGG` for this. In older versions the quickest way to aggregate is a SQLCLR function with the second fastest using `FOR XML` with an empty tag to combine all values in a single string. The loop you posted is one of the slowest string aggregation methods

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Agreed and since than I have changed my code but it still gives the same error nothing to do with performance. Its about the error it's throwing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are getting the error because the table previously contained XML.

You don't need a temp table at all. You can just use `STRING_AGG`.

- You should also quote the names using `QUOTENAME`.
- Object names should be in variables declared as `sysname` which is an alias for `nvarchar(128)`
- You should use `sp_executesql` which also allows you to pass parameters.
- `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` is for compatibility only. Use `sys.columns` instead.

```sql
DECLARE @SCHEMA sysname = 'Person';
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME sysname = 'Person';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
SELECT CONCAT(' + (
    SELECT STRING_AGG('CAST(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' AS nvarchar(max))', ',
  ') + ')'
    FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    WHERE t.name = @TABLE_NAME
      AND s.name = @SCHEMA
) + '
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TABLE_NAME) + ';';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;  -- can also pass parameters
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply I used your method it turns out it works fine without concat function as you have done, but it gives the same error when I try to concat it all as I originally tried.

Comment: See update. You can just put a cast in there, although I'm not sure why you want to concat everything in the first place.

Comment: Thank you very much @Charlieface it works fine. I did not consider the data type of individual columns I was Concatenating which was the error from start.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @SCHEMA VARCHAR(25) = 'PERSON';
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(25) = 'PERSON';

DECLARE @columnlist varchar(max);

SELECT @columnlist = string_agg(COLUMN_NAME, ', ')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
   TABLE_SCHEMA = @SCHEMA 
   AND TABLE_NAME = @TABLE_NAME;

SELECT @columnlist;
```

Comment: HI, @Mitch_Wheat thanks for the response your method of getting columnlist is much more elegant, Although the problem is not that I am not able to use columnlist in my query thus generating error even when I use your method to populate columnlist

Comment: For some reason when I use columnlist in a query it tends to think of it as XML format although its exclusively defined nvarchar

Answer (score 0):

Building on Mitch Wheat noted you will need to convert all the Columns to text first. Using the Cast(col as varchar(max))

Ie can you just use

```
DECLARE @SCHEMA VARCHAR(25) = 'PERSON';
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(25) = 'PERSON';

DECLARE @columnlist varchar(max);

Select  @columnlist = string_agg(ColAsString, ', ') from (
select 'CAST(' + COLUMN_NAME + ' as nvarchar(max))' as ColAsString
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
   TABLE_SCHEMA = @SCHEMA 
   AND TABLE_NAME = @TABLE_NAME) as Data

--SELECT @columnlist;

Declare @SQL as NVARCHAR(max)
Select  @SQL = 'Select CONCAT(' + @columnlist + ' ) as ALLINONE from ' + @SCHEMA + '.' + @TABLE_NAME

Exec(@SQL)
```

Comment: I am tring to concat all of them in one single column and concat(*) does not work hence all this

Comment: HI, @Kevin Bosch I have tried that it does not work. Its still considers it to be a XML instead of varchar. even after explicit conversion